# Ember component unit tests fail with or without ember-qunit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I am doing a spike of migrating my existing ASP.NET MVC server rendered application to a client rendered EmberJS application. There were some hoops to jump through to get everything working from the product side with a very minimal component (basically I just wanted to see if EmberJS components were feasible to develop/test). But alas I have spent hours trying to get a basic component rendering unit test to work.

I have searched all over SO and the rest of the internet but havent found much help. I have basically tried two methods to get this to work:

#### Method #1

With Ember-Qunit. This is basically following the guidance from the official guide ([Testing Components](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-components/)) but for some reason it thinks there are multiple Ember applications on the page:

> You cannot use the same root element (#ember-testing) multiple times in an Ember.Application

Here is the JSBin for this attempt: http://jsbin.com/wotamo/12/edit

#### Method #2

There was this one interesting [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978005/ember-component-testing) here that did it without Ember-Qunit by instantiating a controller and view and having those build up a basic UI that has your component. Their JSBin works but when I modify it to be even slightly more complex (the component has a select element that takes parameters) it completely fails:

> View requires a container

Here is the JSBin for this attempt: http://jsbin.com/ratasi/13/edit